# Real Schur form: eigenbasis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The Real Schur form of a matrix $A$ is a matrix $T$ of the form
$$T = \begin{bmatrix} T_{11} & T_{12} & \cdots & T_{1n} \\
0 & T_{22} & \cdots & T_{2n} \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & T_{nn}
\end{bmatrix},$$
where the $1\times 1$ blocks $T_{ii}$ contain the real eigenvalues and the $2\times 2$ blocks $T_{jj}$ contain complex conjugate eigenvalues. That being said what I'm trying to figure out is the eigenbasis of this kind of matrices, that is, the matrices $X$ of size $n\times 2$ such that
$$ TX = XL. $$
$X$ is the generalization of the eigenvector $-$or *eigenbasis*$-$ for a $2\times 2$ block and $L$ will be the generalization of the eigenvalue for the same $2\times 2$ block.

For a more specific matrix
$$ T = \begin{bmatrix}
\tau_{11} & t_{12}^* & t_{13}^* \\
0 & T_{22} & T_{23} \\
0 & 0 & T_{33}
\end{bmatrix}, $$
where $\tau_{11}$ is a simple eigenvalue, and $T_{22}$ a $2\times 2$ block, I seek eigenbasis of the form
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
x_1^* \\
X_2 \\
X_3
\end{bmatrix}. $$
That is,

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\tau_{11} & t_{12}^* & t_{13}^* \\
0 & T_{22} & T_{23} \\
0 & 0 & T_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^* \\
X_2 \\
X_3
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1^* \\
X_2 \\
X_3
\end{bmatrix}L. $$
Here, the third row yields
$$ T_{33}X_3 = X_3L \Longrightarrow T_{33}X_3 - X_3L = 0, $$
which is a Sylvester equation with solution $X_3 = 0$.
The second row yields
$$ T_{22}X_2 + T_{23}X_3 = X_2L \Longrightarrow T_{22}X_2 - X_2L = -T_{23}X_3, $$
where if we substitute $X_3 = 0$ we have another Sylvester equation with solution $X_2 = 0$. The first row yields
$$ \tau_{11}x_1^* + t_{12}^*X_2 + t_{13}^*X_3 = x_1^*L \Longrightarrow x_1^*(L-\tau_{11}I) = t_{12}^*X_2 + t_{13}^*X_3, $$
where, again, if we substitute $X_2 = X_3 = 0$ we obtain the solution $x_1 = 0$. But there may be a solution for the eigenbasis which is nonzero, and precisely that nonzero solution is what I want to calculate.

Any help will be welcomed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was far easier than I thought after all. Let us start with the equation yield by the third row:
$$ T_{33}X_3 - X_3L = 0. $$
It is a Sylvester's equation with solution $X_3 = 0$. Substituting this in the equation yield by the second row
$$ T_{22}X_2 - X_2L = 0, $$
which is a Sylvester's equation with solution $X_2 = 0$. But since $X_2$ is square, we may require it to be nonsingular. Thus,
$$ L = X_2^{-1}T_{22}X_2. $$
We may choose $X_2$ as we wish, the obvious choice is $X_2 = I$, but other choices generate tidier eigenbases. (If anybody wants further information feel free to ask.) Finally, the first row yields
$$ x_1^*(L-\tau_{11}I) = t_{12}^*X_2, $$
which is a simple linear system.